# Who's the Principal investigator if you are doing your degree project abroad?

Tags: bachelor

**Some necessary information:**

I study at European university A, but did my degree project at European university B.

I will not get a degree from B but from A.

I was supervised by a professor and one of his assistance at B.

My supervisor at A only received regular updates, but wasn't involved in any other way.

Officially the professor at A is grading my work (in reality he probably will just call and ask the professor at university B for the grade, but nonetheless).

**Question:**

I'm currently making the last thing for my thesis: The titlepage. How do I refer to the two professors and the assistant on the titlepage? Who is the supervisor, who the PI? I don't want to step on anybody's toes. I definitely need to mention all three of them.

Furthermore I ask myself whether it is acceptable to put the logo of both universities on the title. I feel like it is weird because I only get a degree from A, but also feel like the professor at B will be offended if I don't.

I know this is a silly question, but maybe you can help me resolve this.

Comment: @gnometorule, that is probably the answer.

Comment: At least in the US, grants have "Principle Investigators."  Theses have supervisors, not PIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a joint email to both professors involved, and ask them what you write here. Showing that you care to do the right thing is unlikely to upset anyone.